# Control field editability based on Permission Set and another field's value

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, permission-sets

I have a requirement that says if Status = closed and the user has a certain permission set, then they should not be able to edit fields that I have on an LWC edit page (lightning-record-edit-form). If Status is anything else, then editing is enabled. Also, there will be another permission set where editability is maintained even if Status = closed.

Validation rules have been considered, but I think it would be cooler if they just can't edit a field rather than show an error message.
Should I check for permission set membership and Status value in my LWC and turn editability on/off accordingly? Or is there a recommended way to configure this point and click? Or is there a better approach?

Comment: lightning-record-view-form itself cannot do this (did you mean lightning-record-edit-form?). You would need to conditionally render either lightning-input-field or lightning-output-field for each field you care about, with relevant condition to select which to render.

Comment: yes. lightning-record-edit-form. copy/pasted the wrong thing. Fixed above. 
OK. this is the best approach in your opinion - in the code check for Status value and Permission Set membership and conditionally render lightning-input/output-fields accordingly?

Comment: If the perm set is just for field access and the "Status" value is to make it read/write on top of that, you don't need to worry about the perm set - the lightning-input-field becomes read only (or even disappears) if you don't have permissions. So you just need to conditionally check the relevant status and choose to render lightning-input-field or lightning-output-field accordingly and let those components decide how to address basic CRUD/FLS permissions.

Comment: @PhilW - what if I have two perm sets that allow edit to a group of fields. If the status = closed, I want users from permset1 to have no edit access. Permset2 should still have edit access. I would have to check to see which permset they have to make that happen, right?

Comment: You probably should be thinking about using a custom permission, rather than checking assignment of specific perm sets. Simply create the custom permission, assign it to the perm set(s) that should be able to do what you want - check the user having the permission.